# Polynomial Interpolation with derivatives

Tags: fortran, interpolation

I made a post about this issue a few weeks ago and edited it but I'm not sure if it's still active. So since it is still bothering me I'm making a new one but in a better form, I hope.

For an assignment I am supposed to interpolate function values and derivative values in newton form. I can do it on paper but I'm completely lost when it comes to turning it into a fortran code. I have looked at different source codes but they either opened a file or asked for input, I was given 5 sets of values and have to use those. I was able to write a small program that will do the interpolation without the derivatives. Then I tried to add the derivatives to it.
In the code below "yp" is for the derivatives

```
program main
implicit none

double precision , allocatable , dimension (:,:) :: nt
double precision , allocatable , dimension (:) :: xnodes, yval, yp
double precision :: x, evalnewton
integer :: i,n,k

n = 7
allocate ( xnodes (0:n), yval (0:n), yp (0:n), nt (0:n, 0:n) )

xnodes = (/ 1.32d0, 2.47d0, 5.81d0, 6.83d0, 7.0d0 /)
yval = (/ 5.63d0, 6.11d0, 8.12d0, 4.33d0, 6.15d0 /)
yp = (/ 1.29d0, 2.21d0, 1.48d0, -3.61d0, 3.11d0 /)

call computent (n, xnodes, yval, yp, nt)

do i = 0,n
    x = xnodes(i)
    print*, xnodes(i), yval(i), yp(i), evalnewton (n, xnodes, nt, x)
end do

open (unit = 4, file = 'z', status = 'replace')

do i = 0,100
    x = dble(i) * 1.0d-1
    write (4,*) x, evalnewton (n, xnodes, nt, x)
end do

close (4)

deallocate (xnodes, yval, yp)

stop
end


subroutine computent (n, xnodes, yval, yp, nt)
implicit none

integer :: i, j, n, k, top, bot
double precision :: nt (0:n, 0:n)
double precision xnodes (0:n), yval (0:n), yp(0:n)
double precision :: x, evalnewton

nt = 0.0d0

do i = 0,n
    nt (i,0) = yval (i) 
end do

do k = 1,n
    top = k
    bot = 0


    do i = k,n
        nt (i,k) = (nt (i,k-1) - nt (i-1,k-1))/(xnodes(top) - xnodes(bot))
        top = top + 1
        bot = bot + 1
    end do


    print*, 'Column number', k
    do j = 0,n
        print*, nt (j,k)
    end do

end do

return
end


double precision function evalnewton (n, xnodes, nt, x)
implicit none

integer :: i, j, n, k, top, bot
double precision :: nt(0:n, 0:n)
double precision xnodes (0:n), yval(0:n), yp(0:n)
double precision :: x

evalnewton = nt(n,n)
do i = n, 1, -1
    evalnewton = evalnewton * (x - xnodes (i-1)) + nt (i-1, i-1)
end do


return
end
```

To be honest I just added "yp" everywhere, where I had "yval" and hoped for a mystery solver to do its magic. I have not figured out yet what to add so the program will include the derivatives in the calculations. It would be nice if someone could explain me the next steps to take.

EDIT: 
I added minor changes to computent which I thought would solve the issue:
    do i = 0,n
        nt (i*2,0) = yval (i)
        nt (i*2+1,0) = yval (i)
    end do

```
do k = 1,n
    top = k 
    bot = 0  


    do i = k,n
        nt (i,k) = (nt (i,k-1) - nt (i-1,k-1))/(xnodes(top) - xnodes(bot))
        if (nt(i,k) == 0) then
            nt(i,k) = yp(i/2)
        end if
        top = top + 2
        bot = bot + 2
    end do


    print*, 'Column number', k
    do j = 0,n
        print*, nt (j,k)
    end do
```

now as first number I get 2.420...e^-322, and that number is messing up the rest of the calculations. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Only glanced at this but one very strange thing is that you make space for 8 entities in your arrays and then set only 5 values. What value do you expect xnodes(7) to take in the subroutine computent? I also strongly suggest you always develop using the array bounds checking and (if available) uninitialized variable checking features on your compiler and see what happens ... Finally your Fortran is a little old fashioned. If you are learning the language at least look into Kinds, contained and module subprograms, and Intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty I figured it out with a small issue. I have it as answer just in case someone else needs it.

```
program main
implicit none

double precision , allocatable , dimension (:,:) :: yt
double precision , allocatable , dimension (:) :: xnodes, yval, yp, xt
double precision :: x, evalnewton
integer :: i,n,k

n = 9
allocate ( xnodes (0:n), yval (0:n), yp (0:n), yt (0:n, 0:n), xt (0:n) )

xnodes = (/ 1.32d0, 2.47d0, 5.81d0, 6.83d0, 7.0d0 /)
yval = (/ 5.63d0, 6.11d0, 8.12d0, 4.33d0, 6.15d0 /)
yp = (/ 1.29d0, 2.21d0, 1.48d0, -3.61d0, 3.11d0 /)

call computent (n, xnodes, yval, yp, yt, xt)

do i = 0,n
    x = xnodes(i)
    print*, xnodes(i), yval(i), yp(i), evalnewton (n, xnodes, yt, x)
end do

open (unit = 4, file = 'z', status = 'replace')

do i = 0,100
    x = dble(i) * 1.0d-1
    write (4,*) x, evalnewton (n, xnodes, yt, x)
end do

close (4)

deallocate (xnodes, yval, yp, yt, xt)

stop
end


subroutine computent (n, xnodes, yval, yp, yt, xt)
implicit none

integer :: i, j, n, k, top, bot
double precision :: yt (0:n, 0:n)
double precision xnodes (0:n), yval (0:n), yp(0:n), xt (0:n)
double precision :: x, evalnewton

xt = 0.0d0
yt = 0.0d0

do i = 0,n
    xt(i*2) = xnodes (i)
    xt(i*2+1) = xnodes (i)
    yt(i*2,0) = yval (i)
    yt(i*2+1,0) = yval (i)  
end do

do k = 1,n

    do i = k,n
        yt(i,k) = (yt(i,k-1) - yt(i-1,k-1))/(xt(i) - xt(i-1))
        if (xt(i) - xt(i-1) == 0) then
            yt(i,k) = yp(i/2)
        end if

    end do

    print*, 'Column number', k
    do j = 0,n
        print*, yt (j,k)
    end do

end do

return
end


double precision function evalnewton (n, xnodes, yt, x)
implicit none

integer :: i, j, n, k, top, bot
double precision :: yt(0:n, 0:n)
double precision xnodes (0:n), yval(0:n), yp(0:n)
double precision :: x

evalnewton = yt(n,n)
do i = n, 1, -1
    evalnewton = evalnewton * (x - xnodes (i-1)) + yt (i-1, i-1)
end do


return
end
```

the small issue is that I get an error message when I run the program and the file is not created

Error Message:
 a.out: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error: